# Send Email with PHP Form - All Form inputs are blank

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm a complete noob to PHP but for a recent web project it's been a requirement to send out emails. From research on the web, this site included it seemed a pretty straightforward thing to do. Everytime I submit the form the PHP runs fine but all of my form fields are blank, they are available in the _POST array but never have any content

**HTML**:

```
<form action="~/includes/form_31804.php" novalidate method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">
                    Name
                </label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control form-row" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company">
                    Company
                </label>
                <input id="company" name="company" class="form-control form-row" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">
                    Email
                </label>
                <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-row" type="email" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="subject">
                    Subject
                </label>
                <input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control form-row" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">
                    Message
                </label><textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control form-row" rows="2" cols="50" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="bloc-button btn btn-d btn-lg pull-right btn-sq bttn1-blue diagonal-fill diagonal-white" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_POST['submit'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $to = "james@soursquare.co.uk"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $subject = "New Website Enquiry";
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $fullMessage = 'Email from: ' . $from . '/nEmail Address: ' . $from . '/nCompany: ' . $company . '/nMessage: ' . $message;

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$fullMessage, $headers);
    header('Location: /thankyou');
}
?>
```

If I create a simple php script to test the mail function it works fine, so it has to be something with the communication between form and php. For what it's worth, the website is running on Windows Server 2012 in IIS/

This has been frustrating me for a good few hours now, so any suggestions would be great.

**Edit**

Not sure if this is relevant, but if I look at what is being passed in $_POST all I get is an empty array. Could there be something on my web server stopping it? Im running Windows Server 2012

Comment: Do a `print_r($SPOST)` at the beginning of your PHP file (just below the `<?php` tag) and then view your source after loading the page. What do you see?

Comment: First of all you need to sanitze your input, as usual with post get session and request values. But have you tried to replacr the variables inside mail() with static values just to debug a bit, does it even reach your if statement, does it redirect you with header, is php mail active on your server using phpinfo(), all steps to debug a bit. Besides that i am wondering what the purpose is of putting the submit value into a text file. Show us some more info on what is not working (and what is). Edit: why do you have required fields, but your form sends a novalidate?

Comment: Is it possible that your web server does not have write permission to  newfile? Have you checked your PHP logs to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: Thanks for the responses everybody. There are definately write permissions to the file as the last modified date changes, I'll try the print_r tomorrow though to see if that helps . Php mail is definately active because if I run a sample script it sends the email fine, I also don't get the redirect. The no validate is hangover from a previous implementation, it's now been removed.

Comment: Can you try without using the tilde (~) in the action path?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no change :(

Answer (score -1):

James.

First, check if you have a submit click on the button.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Setup your variables here.
}
```

If you intend to create just a project for testing and something simple for school, that is fine, but it is NOT recommended at all to use this code on a production environment, because it is not safe.

Please also check your action path file if is correct. I have tested your form on my local machine, and it's work fine. Just with checking submit button.

Comment: Thanks for  the response, i originally checked submit but changed to check email simply as a test. The action file is definately correct as the last modified date of my file changed. There is just no content. Are the any iis settings that could affect it?

Comment: Wht type of message or result do you receive just after press the submit button?

Comment: I get taken to the PHP, but just displays a blank page. I guess this is because it hits the IF statement doesn't meet the criteria so nothing else happens

Comment: First please check if condition is set.
`if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    # code...
} else {
    die("error.");
}`

Comment: Yes if i use this I just get the word "error" on a blank page